# Amazon Web services Kinesis Streams data encryption at rest

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Using AWS Kinesis **Streams**, is the data stored in streams encrypted at rest (during the 24 hr data retention)?
As per [PutRequest Java Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/model/PutRecordRequest.html#setData%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29), setData method does **base64 encoding** by default. Outside this, I did not find any option for encrypting the ByteBuffer data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data pushed into Kinesis is not encrypted at rest. Application that push and read the data needs to handle encrypt/decrypt functionality.